# Prevent objc block from copying propery

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, objective-c-blocks

I have a paged `UITableView` displaying only one item at a time. Each item is a picture fetched from internet. I download my images asynchronously using block :

```
- (void)downloadImageForPost:(GifPost *)p atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  [APIDownloader imageForSource:p.src
                     completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                       if (self.currentIndex != index)
                         return;

                       [self.tableView
                        reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index
                                                                    inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                     }];
}
```

The problem is in `if (self.currentIndex != index)` where `self.currentIndex` is modified outside the block. Say that I call this function for all my images  and that `self.currentIndex = 0`. If I scroll to another index, as `self.currentIndex` was saved at the execution, my if condition does not work.

Is there a way to prevent a block from copying a specified variable. If there is not, what could I do to have the proper behaviour ?

PS: I'm not doing anything with `data`, just calling this function to put it in my cache.

Comment: `self.currentIndex` will already *not* be captured. It's a method call, not a local variable. `index` on the other hand, will be captured at the time the block is created.

Comment: You are right, the problem was not coming from here but in the way I was updating `self.currentIndex`. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Even if you were using something like `_currentIndex`, an instance variable, it would still not be captured, as it is not a local variable. The local variable that is captured would be `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew Madsen said, `self.currentIndex` is a method call. My mistake was coming from where I was updating `self.currentIndex`.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use weak references to self to prevent retain cycles:

```
- (void)downloadImageForPost:(GifPost *)p atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   __weak ClassForSelf *weakSelf = self;
  [APIDownloader imageForSource:p.src
                 completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                   if (weakSelf.currentIndex != index)
                     return;

                   [weakSelf.tableView
                    reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index
                                                                inSection:0]]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The compiler only warns me when I am trying to modify a object itself, not a property of it.

Comment: You may not get a crash or leak with your implementation, but you absolutely 100% will not with mine and a weak reference

Comment: There was no retain cycle in the original, as `self` doesn't retain the block.

Comment: But you have no idea what that class is doing with the block. If it hangs onto it the caller will never get released.